# Как вставить необходимые данные в нужные места?

Tags: ruby

Есть строка:

```
Привет, []. Вы находитесь: []. Время: [].
```

Она находится в одном поле записи в таблице.

Также есть массив с тремя значениями:

```
['Андрей', 'Москва', '14:34:06']
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как их вставить в строку?

Comment: [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split), [`zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) и [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)?

Comment: @D-side вроде эти методы знакомы и в целом принцип их работы ясен, но что-то не понимаю как все это скомбинировать...  Как в `.zip` реализовать подмену после `.split`?

Comment: Обращаю внимание, что ни один из этих методов не осуществляет прямой подмены внутри строк.

Comment: @D-side это я понял, поэтому и задал вопрос выше.

Comment: А это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос. В подмене нет необходимости. Подсказка: `[["Привет, ", "Андрей"], [". Вы находитесь: ", "Москва"], [". Время: ", "14:34:06"], [".", nil]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Простейший вариант может быть таким:

```
s = 'Привет, []. Вы находитесь: []. Время: [].'
a = ['Андрей', 'Москва', '14:34:06']
puts(s.split('[]').zip(a).join)
# "Привет, Андрей. Вы находитесь: Москва. Время: 14:34:06."
```

А вообще рекомендовал бы использовать что-то типа такого:

```
s = 'Привет, %{name}. Вы находитесь: %{place}. Время: %{time}.'
h = { name: 'Андрей', place: 'Москва', time: '14:34:06' }
puts(s % h)
# "Привет, Андрей. Вы находитесь: Москва. Время: 14:34:06."
```